# Why Xamarin app do not run when adding image property to a button

Tags: xaml, xamarin

My problem is that I've a simple app with 2 buttons when I set their text property to any text the app runs and buttons too . When I remove the text property and add an image the app doesn't run but it doesn't throw any exceptions or errors

Note : I've attached the icon's images of the button to the Android.Resources.Drawable

This is the XAML Code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="PhotoGallery.Gallery"
             BackgroundColor="Black">
    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <Image Source="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080" x:Name="pic" Aspect="AspectFit" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"></Image>
        <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding Source={x:Reference pic} , Path=IsLoading}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.1,100,100" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"></ActivityIndicator>
        <Button Image="left.png" x:Name="btnPrevious" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.05 , 0.05 , 150 , 50" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"></Button>
        <Button Image="right.png" x:Name="btnNext" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.95 , 0.05 , 150 , 50" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"></Button>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Option1: Make sure you have included image in drawable folder by right click on image and selecting Include, If you have added image from outside the project. Option2: Remove existing image from folder and add it from project again by right click on drawable-> add existing item->add your image.

Comment: I have already added them through option 2 . I tried even to include the images in the main solution but still get the same problem

Comment: Just to test, design your elements with `StackLayout` instead of `AbsoluteLayout`, may be `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds` is not at proper position and your image is not displaying due to that reason.

Comment: Same problem , I got tired searching and trying things . when I set the **Source** property to a url it works fine but not images on my hard disk even included in the solution

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the buttons are not required, why don't you replace them with images:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="PhotoGallery.Gallery"
             BackgroundColor="Black">
    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <Image Source="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080" x:Name="pic" Aspect="AspectFit" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"></Image>
        <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding Source={x:Reference pic} , Path=IsLoading}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.1,100,100" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"></ActivityIndicator>
        <Image Source="left.png" x:Name="btnPrevious" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.05 , 0.05 , 150 , 50" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional">
            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnPreviousImageTapped"  />
            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>
        <Image Source="right.png" x:Name="btnNext" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.95 , 0.05 , 150 , 50" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional">
            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnNextImageTapped"  />
            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: It seems I'm having a problem with images attached to Android.Resources , when I tried your solution the app run but left.png and right.png doesn't appear . Any suggestions about what would I've made wrong ?